# Proportion distributions at different hierarchical levels

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large dataset with 50000 rows and 20 different columns. All of these columns are categorical and the categories vary from 2 to 12. I need to data to be proportioned down by categories. After a certain level, the variables will be distributed as binary if there exists multiple levels.

A sample data looks like below. It has three columns `Ate`, `Ali`, and `Wea.` `Ate` has two factors: `m,` and `n`. `Ali` has three factors: `A`, `B`, and `C`. `Wea` has three: `d`, `e`, and `r`.

```
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Ate Ali Wea
1   m   A   d
2   m   B   d
3   m   C   d
4   n   B   r
5   n   C   d
6   n   C   r
7   n   A   e
8   m   A   e
9   m   B   d
10  m   C   d
11  n   B   e
12  n   C   d
13  n   C   r
14  n   A   r
15  m   B   e
16  m   B   r
17  n   B   r      
                   ")
dat1
   ID Ate Ali Wea
1   1   m   A   d
2   2   m   B   d
3   3   m   C   d
4   4   n   B   r
5   5   n   C   d
6   6   n   C   r
7   7   n   A   e
8   8   m   A   e
9   9   m   B   d
10 10   m   C   d
11 11   n   B   e
12 12   n   C   d
13 13   n   C   r
14 14   n   A   r
15 15   m   B   e
16 16   m   B   r
17 17   n   B   r
```

We need to convert the characters to factors.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dat1 <- dat1 %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
summary(dat1)
       ID     Ate   Ali   Wea  
 Min.   : 1   m:8   A:4   d:7  
 1st Qu.: 5   n:9   B:7   e:4  
 Median : 9         C:6   r:6  
 Mean   : 9                    
 3rd Qu.:13                    
 Max.   :17
```

As the data has 3 columns, the proportion will be distributed in three levels. In the first level, the first column is `Ate`. This level has two factors: `m`, and `n`. So, the distribution will be `m= 8/17=47%` and `n=9/17=53%`. In the next level, `m` and `n` will be distributed by `A`, `B`, `C`. Under `m`, there are `A=2, B=4, and C=2`. So, the distribution will be `A=2/8=25%, B=4/8=50%, and C=2/8=25%`. The distribution for `n`, at second level, will be similar to `m`.

In the third level, the data has six combinations: `m A`, `m B`, `m C`, `n A`, `n B`, and `n C`. For example, `m A` has only 2 entries: `m A d`, `m A e`. So, this level `d`, and `e` are distributed as `50%` and `50%`. Another example, `m B` has 4 entries and three classes: `m B d: 2, m B e: 1, m B r:1`. From Level 3, we want binary classes as the top two classes. So, this level, `m B` will have two entries: `m B d: 50%, m B Others: 50%` by combining `e` and `r` into a new category `Others`. The final outcome will be like below. As this is a sample data, the solution will need to consider multiple levels in presence of multiple columns.

```
   Lev1 Lev2   Lev3 Perc
1     m   na     na   47
2     n   na     na   53
3     m    A     na   25
4     m    B     na   50
5     m    C     na   25
6     n    A     na   22
7     n    B     na   44
8     n    C     na   33
9     m    A      d   50
10    m    A      e   50
11    m    B      d   50
12    m    B Others   50
13    m    C      d   100
14    m    C Others   0
15    n    A      e   50
16    n    A      r   50
17    n    B      r   63
18    n    B Others   37
19    n    C      d   50
20    n    C      r   50
```

**Follow up:**
*Robert provided an excellent solution. However, if I add a column, the code provides partial results.*

```
dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Ate Ali Wea Ght
1   m   A   d   p
2   m   B   d   p
3   m   C   d   y
4   n   B   r   t
5   n   C   d   y
6   n   C   r   y
7   n   A   e   y
8   m   A   e   p
9   m   B   d   y
10  m   C   d   t   
11  n   B   e   t
12  n   C   d   p
13  n   C   r   p
14  n   A   r   p
15  m   B   e   y
16  m   B   r   y
17  n   B   r   p     
                   ")
dat2
   ID Ate Ali Wea Ght
1   1   m   A   d   p
2   2   m   B   d   p
3   3   m   C   d   y
4   4   n   B   r   t
5   5   n   C   d   y
6   6   n   C   r   y
7   7   n   A   e   y
8   8   m   A   e   p
9   9   m   B   d   y
10 10   m   C   d   t
11 11   n   B   e   t
12 12   n   C   d   p
13 13   n   C   r   p
14 14   n   A   r   p
15 15   m   B   e   y
16 16   m   B   r   y
17 17   n   B   r   p
```

*See results below. For example, at third level (see row `11` and `12`. `m B` has two categories: `m B d` and `m B Others`. In the forth level, `m B d` is expanded but not `m B Others`.*

```
 hier_props(dat2, col.bin='Wea')
   Ate  Ali    Wea    Ght Perc
1    m <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   47
2    n <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   53
3    m    A   <NA>   <NA>   25
4    m    B   <NA>   <NA>   50
5    m    C   <NA>   <NA>   25
6    n    A   <NA>   <NA>   22
7    n    B   <NA>   <NA>   33
8    n    C   <NA>   <NA>   44
9    m    A      d   <NA>   50
10   m    A      e   <NA>   50
11   m    B      d   <NA>   50
12   m    B Others   <NA>   50
13   m    C      d   <NA>  100
14   m    C Others   <NA>    0
15   n    A      e   <NA>   50
16   n    A      r   <NA>   50
17   n    B      e   <NA>   33
18   n    B      r   <NA>   67
19   n    C      d   <NA>   50
20   n    C      r   <NA>   50
21   m    A      d      p  100
22   m    A      d Others    0
23   m    A      e      p  100
24   m    A      e Others    0
25   m    B      d      p   50
26   m    B      d      y   50
27   m    C      d      t   50
28   m    C      d      y   50
29   n    A      e      y  100
30   n    A      e Others    0
31   n    A      r      p  100
32   n    A      r Others    0
33   n    B      e      t  100
34   n    B      e Others    0
35   n    B      r      p   50
36   n    B      r      t   50
37   n    C      d      p   50
38   n    C      d      y   50
39   n    C      r      p   50
40   n    C      r      y   50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a way to do it:

```r
#  dat       data
#  col.from  index of the first level column
#  col.bin   name of the first binary column
hier_props <- function(dat, col.from=2, col.bin) {
  
  ## Processes one hierarchical level
  #  d            data without the already processed columns
  #  prev.categs  categories from previous levels in this branch
  #  col.i        current column's index
  process_level <- function(d, prev.categs, col.i) {
    
    categ.tab <- table(d[, 1])
    remove.others <- F
    
    # (possibly) introduce 'Others' for binary levels
    if (col.i >= col.bin) {
      
      # add zero for Others when only one category is present
      if (length(categ.tab) == 1) {
        
        categ.tab <- c(categ.tab, Others = 0)
        remove.others <- T   # flag Others for future removal
        
      # keep only the most represented category and merged Others
      } else if (length(categ.tab) > 2) {
        
        i.max <- which.max(categ.tab)
        categ.tab <- c(categ.tab[i.max], Others = sum(categ.tab[-i.max]))
        d[d[, 1] != names(categ.tab)[1], 1] <- 'Others'
      }
    }
    
    categ.tab <- round(categ.tab / nrow(d) * 100)  # percentages
    # create a list of list representations of rows for the current categories
    now <- mapply(c, 
                  list(as.list(prev.categs)), 
                  names(categ.tab), 
                  list(rep(NA, ncol(d)-1)),
                  categ.tab, 
                  SIMPLIFY=F)
    # change lists to data frames, set names and save them to the 'out' variable
    #   stored within parent function
    out <<- c(out, lapply(now, \(x) setNames(as.data.frame(x), 
                                             c(names(dat), 'Perc'))))
    # remove Others when only one category was present so that it is not used
    #   in the lower hierarchical level
    if (remove.others) categ.tab <- categ.tab[names(categ.tab) != 'Others']
    
    # go one hierarchicel level deeper
    if (ncol(d) > 1) {
      for (categ in names(categ.tab)) {
        
        d.categ <- d[d[, 1]==categ, -1, drop=F]
        process_level(d.categ, c(prev.categs, categ), col.i+1)
      }
    }
  }
  
  out <- list()
  # keep only level columns
  dat <- dat[, seq(col.from, ncol(dat))]
  # name of the first 'binary' column
  col.bin <- which(names(dat) == col.bin)
  # start processing from the first column
  process_level(dat, NULL, 1)
  
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  out <- out[order(rowSums(is.na(out)), decreasing=T), ]
  rownames(out) <- seq_len(nrow(out))
  out
}
```

It basically computes the percentages for the first level, saves them, takes subsets of the data for each of this level's categories, removes this level and proceeds recursively as long as there are any columns left. I hope my comments can help understand what the code does.

And here's the result:

```r
hier_props(dat1, col.bin='Wea')
#    Ate  Ali    Wea Perc
# 1    m <NA>   <NA>   47
# 2    n <NA>   <NA>   53
# 3    m    A   <NA>   25
# 4    m    B   <NA>   50
# 5    m    C   <NA>   25
# 6    n    A   <NA>   22
# 7    n    B   <NA>   33
# 8    n    C   <NA>   44
# 9    m    A      d   50
# 10   m    A      e   50
# 11   m    B      d   50
# 12   m    B Others   50
# 13   m    C      d  100
# 14   m    C Others    0
# 15   n    A      e   50
# 16   n    A      r   50
# 17   n    B      e   33
# 18   n    B      r   67
# 19   n    C      d   50
# 20   n    C      r   50
```